# Razor : Where is Server side controls

Tags: razor, toolbox

I am new to MVC 3. When I generated a file called NewEmployee.cshtml, I could see only HTML controls.

1. Where is the server side controls ?
2. If it does not support those controls, why should I go for Razor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC is a different way of building websites/applications to webforms.

You should have a look at some of the tutorials on www.asp.net to see the differences.

Answers:
1) There are no server side controls
2) There are other benefits to using Razor (or aspx) within the MVC model. UI development is simpler/separated and helps when building interfaces with jQuery, no fighting with webcontrols and microsoft ajax.

HTH

Comment: Yes, however, have a look at jQuery, jquery ajax and the plugins available, this keeps html very lightweight and are easy for designers to style than webcontrols. If you want to use commercial component, MVC components also exist from some vendors.